# How to calculate the probability of guessing 6 digit number in x attempts

Tags: probability

I want to calculate the probability of someone guessing a 6 digit number, in x attempts.

I easily found how to calculate the probability of guessing the number once, which is: 1/10^6

But how do I change this to allow for x number of guesses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say, you have $N$ total possibilities ($10^6$ in your case). Probability of guessing the correct number at $x$-th guess means $x-1$ wrong guesses followed by a correct guess, that is ($x>1$): $$p_x=\frac{N-1}{N}\frac{N-2}{N-1}...\frac{N-x+1}{N-x+2}\frac{1}{N-x+1}=\frac{1}{N}$$

Probability of guessing the correct number *upto* (and including) $x$-th guess is
$$\sum_{k=1}^x p_k=\frac{x}{N}$$

One intuitive way to think the latter is the coverage of your guesses. You cover $x$ out of $N$ guesses in total, which means $x/N$ is the probability that you'll guess the correct number in at most $x$ guesses.

**Edit**, assumptions to recall:

- Guesser guesses numbers without replacement (i.e. won't guess the same number again if wrong) and equiprobable
- The selection of the random 6-digit number is equiprobable among all possibililities

Comment: This is a good analysis.  I would like to suggest any interest in the question, though, lies in uncovering the assumptions required to justify this kind of analysis.  Among those assumptions we might include (1) guessing can be modeled by equiprobable random sampling without replacement; (2) the determination of the number can be modeled as an equiprobable random selection; (3) this is a one-off procedure rather than one play in a long game of similar plays.  The latter is particularly interesting because it suggests circumstances in which this answer would be incorrect.

Comment: @whuber thanks, I had left the first two out of the answer just for the sake of simplicity, now included them. But, I couldn't understand what you meant by (3)

Comment: As an extreme example, imagine a game between two players where the first selects the number and the second attempts to guess it. What would be the solution if, say, *both* players incurred a loss directly proportional to $x$ and they could play the game repeatedly?

Comment: @gunes thanks. I am trying to understand the notation. I ended up with a few different numbers. Could you tell me the probability as a percent if N = 10^6 and there are 3 guesses. Is it 0.0006%?

Comment: (finding the correct number upto 3 guesses) It'll be 3/10^6, so 0.000003, which means 0.0003%.